# COUNT and GROUP BY using Zend Framework 2 and tableGateway

Tags: zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2, using tableGateway, I want to run the following SQL query:

```
  SELECT categories.category_name, COUNT(forums.forum_id)
    FROM categories LEFT JOIN forums
      ON categories.category_id = forums.category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name;
```

Problem is that I simply don't know how to do it. I know how to use `$select->join()` for example, but I can't figure out how to also do a `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

What I want with my SQL: I have 2 tables; `categories` and `forums`. I want to select all the categories from `categories` and for each category I want the amount of forums.

Comment: Check around with [`Zend\Db\Sql\Expression()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Expression.php), should be something like `$select->(new Expression('COUNT(forums.forum_id) AS ForumCount');`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Someone on another forum gave me the correct answer, and this works for me. Thought I would share it in case anyone else is having a similar question. Here is how I have it now:

`use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;`

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select)
{
    // Select columns and count the forums.
    $select->columns(array(
        'category_name',
        'forumsCount' => new Expression('COUNT(forums.forum_id)')
    ));

    // Left-join with the forums table.
    $select->join('forums', 'categories.category_id = forums.category_id', array(), 'left');

    // Group by the category name.
    $select->group('categories.category_name');
});

return $resultSet;
```

Comment: can you pls share that link, so that we can get the other things too like limit, where and all..

Comment: @kumar my question did not involve `limit` or `where` statements, so it is not in the answer either.

Comment: how can we pass parameter inside the block

Comment: @khunshan simply add `use ($var)` to the very end of the first line in my answer's code. The variable `$var` can be defined in the method before the `tableGateway` function, or can come from the method's parameter.

Comment: yes i got it. we have to pass scope in closure. thanks @Nic

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks right. Does it work as expected when you run it directly on the database.

I think you might just need to execute the raw query using an adapter.

```
$sql = "SELECT categories.category_name, COUNT(forums.forum_id) FROM categories LEFT JOIN forums ON     categories.category_id = forums.category_id GROUP BY categories.category_name";

$statement = $this->adapter->query($sql);
return $statement->execute();
```

Comment: I can't get that to work with tableGateway, unfortunately. And I was really hoping to use the available methods rather than putting down the actual SQL. And yes, when I run the query in PhpMyAdmin it works just fine.